# SQL Server Full Outer Join Execution Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a query that currently takes ~7 seconds to run, unfortunately I don't know how to get it running faster. I am relatively new to SQL, so I am trying to avoid any easy mistakes.

It takes this long because of the full outer joins that I have on it, but I need what those joins give me.

So, I guess I have four questions:

1. Do full outer joins always slow code down?
2. Am I using full outer joins wrong?
3. Is there something that I can substitute for the full outer joins?
4. Have I made a beginner mistake somewhere?

Code:

```
SELECT
    j.JobId
    , j.OrderId
    , j.OrderType
    , j.ShopName
    , j.ShipDate
    , j.CompletionDate
    , j.InstallDate
    , j.DayPriority
    , j.ShipDateConfirmed
    , j.IsAddon
    , j.CashOnDelivery
    , ds.ShopLabel
    , ds.DesignSetId
    , dsp.DesignSetProcessId
    , dsp.DueDate AS DesignSetProcessDueDate
    , dsp.DatetimeStarted
    , dsp.DatetimeComplete
    , dsp.BatchNumber
    , p.Name AS ProcessName
    , p.ProcessId
    , p.ZoneId
    , X.CabinetCount
FROM
    Jobs j
JOIN 
    DesignSets ds ON j.JobId = ds.JobId
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    Schedule.DesignSetProcessesWithDueDates dsp ON ds.DesignSetId = dsp.DesignSetId
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    Schedule.Processes p ON dsp.ProcessId = p.ProcessId 
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT
         SUM(pr.Quantity * pr.DeliveryCnt) AS CabinetCount
     FROM
         Products pr
     WHERE
         ds.DesignSetId = pr.DesignSetId
         AND (dsp.BatchNumber = pr.BatchNumber OR dsp.DesignSetId IS NULL)) as X
WHERE
    j.Status >= 60
    AND j.Status <= 70
ORDER BY
    j.CompletionDate
    , j.DayPriority DESC
    , j.ShopName
    , j.OrderId
    , ds.ShopLabel
    , p.SortOrder
    , dsp.BatchNumber
```

**EDIT**

My bad I should have been more specific. The way I found that the full outer joins are slowing the query, was by changing them to left inner joins and getting a faster query, but getting less rows than I need, I need to get 1910 rows. We use azure and they automatically index our database, though I don't know how good it is and I don't know anything about indexes. I am testing the query by just getting into a grid, though I do I call it from an application.

**UPDATE**

Turns out it was a view that I was getting the DueDate from, so dsp.DueDate AS DesignSetProcessDueDate was slowing everything down, I figured out another way to get that information and it runs like a dream now.

Comment: what makes you think it's the full join? Maybe it's missing indexes. Maybe it's out of date statistics. Maybe there are other queries blocking yours. Maybe there is a resource contention that would be shown with sp_Blitz or sp_WhoIsActive. Can you post the **actual** execution plan at https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Also tell us what indexes you have on each of the tables in the query.

Comment: Also tell us how many rows you're getting back and how you're running the query - running in SSMS and sending the results to a grid is slower than running in SSMS and sending them to flat text, which is usually slower than when calling from an application.  Also also, the sub-select to get X.CabinetCount has a `Where` clause that isn't doing you any favors.

Answer (score 1):

You may get a small gain by fixing the `join`s -- `full outer join` is being undone by the `where` clause and it might affect optimization options.

For this query:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM Jobs j JOIN 
     DesignSets ds
     ON j.JobId = ds.JobId LEFT JOIN 
     Schedule.DesignSetProcessesWithDueDates dsp
     ON ds.DesignSetId = dsp.DesignSetId LEFT JOIN 
     Schedule.Processes p
     ON dsp.ProcessId = p.ProcessId OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(pr.Quantity * pr.DeliveryCnt) AS CabinetCount
      FROM Products pr
      WHERE ds.DesignSetId = pr.DesignSetId AND
           (dsp.BatchNumber = pr.BatchNumber OR dsp.DesignSetId IS NULL)
     )  X
WHERE j.Status >= 60 AND j.Status <= 70
```

For this query, you want indexes on:

- `jobs(status, jobid)`
- `designsets(JobId, DesignSetId)`
- `DesignSetProcessesWithDueDates(DesignSetId, ProcessId, BatchNumber)`
- `Processes(ProcessId)`
- `Products(DesignSetId, BatchNumber, Quantity, DeliveryCnt)` (you can include the last two columns rather than having them as keys).